# ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED with GetDc on Windows when using remote desktop

Tags: windows, multithreading, delphi, windows-xp

I have a procedure for screen capture. It works fine in main thread. But I need to do it in work thread. So I get ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED when GetDc is called. I check error with GetLastError. This error I get only on Windows XP machine. Test in Windows Vista and 7 is working ok. Test program is simple GUI with main form (so it is not console program). Thread I have for receiving commands from http client. So this program is actualy http server.

Sorry I found out the problem is elsewhere. Runing test was not same. On XP I used remote desktop but on other Windows I run program normaly loged as normal user. So problem is access to desktop when app runs in background or from remote desktop. I have to find out how to acces to desktop when app is run with remote dekstop.

Comment: GUI handles only accessible by  main thread . you must [Synchronize](http://delphi.about.com/od/kbthread/a/thread-gui.htm) threads

Comment: Note that the documentation for `GetDC` never says you should call `GetLastError`, so the error code might not be accurate.